# Configuring internal padding on Chart.js Bar chart

Tags: chart.js, bar-chart

I am attempting to get Chart.js bar charts to have "internal" left and right padding, such that the bars are centered with minimal width between them, but larger space to the left and right. By default it seems the left and right padding is simply half the space between bars. Looking at the docs, I assumed that I could use the categoryPercentage and barPercentage parameters together to accomplish my task, but it seems that is only for multiple bars within a single column, whereas I have multiple columns with one bar in each. See image for what I am trying to do. Thanks for any insight.

[image: Chart.js default vs desired design]